# How is the integral of a projection over an element $T$ computed in practice? (deal.II related)

Tags: finite-element, error-estimation, quadrature, projection, deal.ii

I'm studying an error estimator for the equation $\nabla\cdot(\beta u) + cu = f$ and it contains the following term $$||f - cU_h - \Pi(f-c U_h) ||_T$$
where :

- $\Pi$ is the local orthogonal $L^2$ projection onto the classical polynomial DG finite element space $\{v \in L^2: v_{|K} \in \mathbb{P}^{r}(K) \}$
- $U_h$ is the finite element solution, which I have on each cell $T$

I'm implementing this in deal.II. Morally what I want to achieve is the computation of that integral over each cell using quadratures, so

$$\sum_{q} \Bigl(f(x_q) - c U_h(x_q) - \Pi(f-cU_h)(x_q) \Bigr) w_q \det(B_T)$$

I recall that $U_h$ is a vector. Luckily, there's already a routine that allows me to compute $U_h(x_q)$, that is named [get_function_values()](https://www.dealii.org/current/doxygen/deal.II/classFEValuesBase.html#a357b422e374f2f2207af3512093f3907)

However, the true issue is the term $\Pi(f-cU_h)(x_q)$, i.e. the projection of that difference, evaluated at the quadrature points.

What is the practical way people follow to compute that kind of expression? I wasn't able to find anything useful on the deal.II documentation (probably I didn't look in the good places).

---

**EDIT:**

I tried to follow the second suggestion given by prof. Bangerth. By definition of $L^2$ projection:
$$(\Pi(f - cU_h), \phi_i) = (f-cU_h, \phi_i)$$ for every test function $\phi_i$ in my dg space. This means that on every cell I can define and solve  $$M_{ij} x_j = (f - c U_h, \phi_i):=F_i$$ where $M_{ij}=(\phi_j,\phi_i)$ is the mass matrix corresponding to a generic cell.

The r.h.s of the equation above is computed by quadrature using the values of $U_h$ at quadrature points (given by the get_function_values() routine), while of course $f$ is a known continuous function evaluated as usual.

I was implementing this by using a MeshWorker framework as done in [step-74](https://www.dealii.org/current/doxygen/deal.II/step_74.html#Aposteriorierrorestimator). That means that the linear system above was put inside the `cell_worker` lambda expression so that, while looping over all the cells, I compute that projection $x$ for every cell and use that  to compute the actual error indicator on each cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compute the projection $\Pi(f-cU_h)$ as a first step. This is a finite element field, so you can create a global field (in deal.II lingo: Create the corresponding finite element and a `DoFHandler` object) and compute it by global projection by inverting a mass matrix. Alternatively, because the field is discontinuous, you can also forgo the global field and just compute the projection locally by inverting a local mass matrix. In either case, you end up with a finite element field on the current cell associated with the discontinuous element, which you can then evaluate at quadrature points like any other finite element field.

Comment: Thanks Prof. Bangerth. I edited my question with what I did in these two days: I didn't create any new DoFHandler object to do this, I used the one I was using in the assembly routine. Does it sound okay to you? @WolfgangBangerth

Comment: @bobinthebox, this answer is great, but I would like to add something. Depending on the polynomial degree of the solution and $f$, you have to use a quadrature rule with higher degree to avoid introducing truncation errors (from the quadrature). Most people use $2p+1$-st degree quadrature rules. But I found that (experientially) even for a simple nice function like $\sin(\pi x)\cos(\pi x)$ over the unit square, $2p+1$ is not enough. So I use $2p+3$-rd degree or higher quadrature rules.

Comment: @bobinthebox It seems reasonable what you describe.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your check. My estimator is almost completed. I'm trying to implement the estimator proposed at equation (4.7) of this paper (https://sci-hub.st/10.1007/978-3-319-01818-8_8). Unfortunately, this involves a reconstruction $\hat{u}$ which is defined elementwise. I've never done such a "reconstruction" and, if I am not mistaken, there's no tutorial which does a similar thing, right? @WolfgangBangerth

Comment: There is no tutorial that shows *exactly* this, but you should take a look at the HDG and WG tutorials (step-51 and 62) to see similar techniques at play.

Comment: I should add that it would be very nice indeed to have your program be part of the code gallery!

Comment: Thanks @WolfgangBangerth . Unfortunately, those steps are not helping me that much, so I created a new question adressing the issue. After this last detail, I'd be very happy to contribute by adding this to the code gallery, after documenting things properly

Comment: @bobinthebox That would be fantastic!