# Global reconstruction defined elementwise in a-posteriori error estimator

Tags: finite-element, c++, error-estimation, advection, deal.ii

This question is a follow-up of this [previous one](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/38943/how-is-the-integral-of-a-projection-over-an-element-t-computed-in-practice-d). In ["Error Control for Discontinuous Galerkin Methods for First Order Hyperbolic Problems"](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-319-01818-8_8) by Georgoulis et al., an error estimator is provided in equation (4.7).

It contains the term $$||f -b \cdot \nabla \hat u - cu_h - \Pi(f-b \cdot \nabla \hat u-c u_h) ||_T$$

where :

- $\Pi$ is the local orthogonal $L^2$ projection onto the classical polynomial DG finite element space $S_h= \{v \in L^2: v_{|T} \in \mathbb{P}^{p}(T) \}$
- $u_h$ is the finite element solution, which I have on each cell $T$
- $\hat{u}$, called *reconstruction*, is defined elementwise (see definition 4.3 or the beginning of Section 4) by the relation $$\int_Tb \cdot \nabla \hat{u} v_h = \int_T b \cdot \nabla u_h v_h - \int_{\partial_{-T}} (b \cdot n)[u_h]v_h^{+}$$
  for all $v_h \in S_h$ (classical DG fe space)

It's written that the reconstruction space is $\{w_h \in C({\bar{\Omega}}): w_{h|T} \in \mathbb{P}^{p+2}(T)\}$

**My big issue is with this reconstruction part!**

As far as I understand, I should construct $\hat{u}$ cell-by-cell by using that definition. Of course, as I know $u_h$ and $v_h$, it turns out that a linear system for each cell has to be solved.

**However**, it seems to me that $\hat{u}$ is in a continuous finite element space, instead of a discontinuous one like $v_h$. So, by expanding the l.h.s I would have

$$(b \cdot \nabla \varphi_j,\phi_i)_T$$

where $\varphi_j$ is a basis function in the continuous finite element space, while $\phi_i$ is a basis function of the discontinuous one $S_h$.

I am a bit confused on how to do this. If I create a different DoFHandler object on the same triangulation, distribute the dofs corresponding to the continuous space, I would not even end up with a square matrix since *I don't have the same number of degrees of freedom in these two spaces*. So I think I am clearly missing the point. Any help is extremely appreciated.

Comment: Have you asked the authors whether they really wanted the space to be continuous? It might be a mistake in the paper's writing.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Thanks for your comment. I haven't actually. Why do you think it may be a mistake?

Comment: Because "cellwise" and "continuous" just doesn't go together.

Comment: Well, I've just spent a whole day trying to figure out how that could possibly be done. I have also to add that if I try to compute that cellwise matrix (4x4 with bilinear functions) with entries $$(b \cdot \nabla \phi_j,\phi_i)_T$$ with $\{\phi_i\}_i$ DG basis functions, that matrix turns out to be singular. Same thing happens if I try with continuous basis functions. (I tried several fields $b$). In the paper they're using triangles. Is it possible that with quads I have a 4by4 singular matrix, but the 3by3 I'd get with triangles is non singular? @WolfgangBangerth

Comment: You mean it's singular because you get zero for a constant $\phi_j$? That would be no different for triangles. I think you need to ask the authors about these questions -- which is a totally normal thing to do, I might add.

Comment: I mean it's singular because I computed its determinant and it's about $10^{-40}$, which means that I would obtain indeed 0 for a constant $\phi_j$. I'm going to ask them and will update this question. Thanks Prof. @WolfgangBangerth